# query over 2 columns where value never appears in either column more than once

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking for a query that takes the following table `ProductList`

```
id| column_1  | column_2  | Sum  
================================  
1 | Product-A | Product-B |  67 
2 | Product-A | Product-C |  55 
3 | Product-A | Product-D |  23 
4 | Product-B | Product-C |  95 
5 | Product-C | Product-D | 110
```

and returns the first record Product-A_Product-B and then skips all records that contain Product-A or Product-B in either column and returns Product-C_Product-D.
I only want to return the row if everything in the row is appearing for the first time.

Comment: without a column to `order by` the concept of *first* is undefined.

Comment: ...although `ORDER BY column_1, column_2` does look like a possibility!

Comment: @Strawberry That's possible, but should be defined by OP.

Comment: Fair enough. You can sort by id or sum

Comment: http://kennethxu.blogspot.nl/2016/04/analytical-function-in-mysql-rownumber.html (in essence, reintroduce the sorely missed rank over partition in MySQL, and put it in a subquery, and select all the rows with rank=1).

Comment: Or perhaps this [explain extended link](https://explainextended.com/2009/03/05/row-sampling/) is more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the products don't contain `,`, you could use a comma-delimited session variable to store already selected products and check for every row if one of the columns is already contained in that variable:

```
select column_1, column_2
from (
    select l.*,
        case when find_in_set(l.column_1, @products) or find_in_set(l.column_2, @products)
          then 1
          else (@products := concat(@products, ',', l.column_1, ',', l.column_2)) = ''
        end as skip
    from ProductList l
    cross join (select @products := '') init
    order by l.id
) t
where skip = 0;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/NDVBW87988

But you should know the risks:

1. `ORDER BY` in a subquery is not really valid and usually doesn't make sence. The engine may skip it or move it to the outer query.
2. If you read and write the same session variable in one statement, the execution order is not defined. So the query might not work for all (future) versions.